# Stripe SDK crash

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up Tap To Pay in iOS using React Native and EXPO.
The problem is, every time I try to discoverReaders the app crash.

This is the component:

```
const DiscoverScreen = () => {
    const [readers, setReaders] = useState([]);

    const { discoverReaders } = useStripeTerminal({
        onUpdateDiscoveredReaders: (newReaders) => {
            // Update your state with the new readers
            setReaders(newReaders);
        },
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // Start discovering readers
        const { error } = discoverReaders({
            discoveryMethod: 'internet',
            simulated: true,
        });

        // Handle any potential errors here
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error discovering readers:', error);
        }

        // No need for cleanup, as the hook should handle unsubscribing
    }, [discoverReaders]);

    return <View />;
};

export default DiscoverScreen;
```

This is my dependencies:

```
`"dependencies": {
   
    "@stripe/stripe-terminal-react-native": "^0.0.1-beta.13",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
   
  }
```

It seems that the problem is something with this discoverReaders method.

Comment: Looks to me like you are missing an `await` before `discoverReaders()` -- this needs to be within an async function and you need to wait for the discover readers promise to resolve before doing anything else.

Comment: even using await it crashes.